# Отменить срабатывание onclick в динамически созданном элементе

Tags: javascript, es5

Есть `js`-код и `HTML`-страница

```js
function ChangeInput(object) {
  let inputObj = document.getElementById("Email");
  let parentDiv = document.getElementById("editBtn").parentNode;
  inputObj.removeAttribute("disabled");
  let saveObj = document.createElement("button");
  saveObj.id = "saveObj";
  saveObj.textContent = "Save";
  saveObj.onclick = function() {
    let parentDiv = document.getElementById("saveObj").parentNode;
    let saveObj = document.getElementById("saveObj");
    let editBtn = document.createElement("button");
    let inputObj = document.getElementById("Email");
    inputObj.addAttribute("disabled");
    editBtn.id = "editBtn";
    editBtn.textContent = "Edit";
    editBtn.onclick = ChangeInput(this);
    parentDiv.appendChild(editBtn);
    saveObj.parentNode.removeChild(saveObj);
  }
  parentDiv.appendChild(saveObj);
  object.parentNode.removeChild(object);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" value="mail@mail.com" disabled />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="ChangeInput(this);" id="editBtn">Edit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

По клику на кнопке `Edit` создается кнопка `Save`. В элемент `Save` добавляется функция, которая должна вызываться по клику же, однако, в этом месте у меня и проблемы. Прошу указать на ошибки. `DOM` только начал изучать. `JQuery` не предлагать, пока `DOM` не освою - в `JQuery` не трогаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Метода addAttribute не существует. Есть `setAttribute`
2. Ему нужно два параметра: setAttribute("disabled", "что-нибудь");
3. cannot read property 'parentNode' of null". Это происходит при втором клике, когда на первом клике вы удаляете "editBtn", а на втором пытаетесь найти его.
4. Интерпретатору всё равно, а человеческий глаз плохо воспринимает большой толстый столбик кода. Если не получается его как-то разбить на блоки/функции - можно хотя бы вставить пробельные строки между небольшими, логически связанными блоками кода.

Если так много используется getElementById, можно придумать коротенькую функцию, которая возвращает то же самое, но удобнее в использовании. Но если много увлекаться этим, через некоторое время можно обнаружить, что вы изобрели jQuery))

Ну а для исправления ошибки, нужен уже другой подход:

```js
let isEditMode = false;

_id("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let input = _id("Email");
  
  this.textContent = isEditMode ? "Edit" : "Save";
  // «Тернарный оператор», Если isEditMode == true, возьмется "Edit", иначе - "Save";

  input.disabled = isEditMode;
  // Вместо setAttribute. Сразу указывается свойство - true/false.

  isEditMode = !isEditMode;
  // `!` - логическое "НЕ". Превращает false ←→ true и наоборот. 
});

function _id(str) {
  return document.getElementById(str);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" value="mail@mail.com" disabled />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="editBtn">Edit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Помимо ряда других причин не использовать onclick в HTML... Если функция вызвана оттуда, консоль не может указывать на строчку ошибки. А вручную искать её в коде - трудно.

P.s. `this.textContent = (input.disabled = (isEditMode = !isEditMode)) ? "Edit" : "Save";` "Умные" строчки кода тоже никому не нужны. Лучше несколько, но понятных строчек.

Comment: *Скорее всего, если повозиться - можно и ваш вариант исправить, с переключениями id. Ниасилил) Нужно только при каждом клике убедиться, что id для следующего клика уже создан. Или, вместо удаления кнопок - переключать, display = "block" / "none";

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, направление движения уловил )